# Cartoon where kids enter virtual world and fight monsters, then leave via towers with targets inside

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I'm 20 years old now sooo I was probably watching this cartoon in mid 2000s. Basically these kids would enter a virtual world through these body portals and fight virtual monsters using special abilities that they received when they entered.

I remember they could be injured a certain number of times while in the virtual world but they had like a mission to complete. One of the kids turned into a cat like character. Then when they wanted to leave the virtual world, they found a tower that had like a target on it and they went inside and jumped off the platform.

Comment: There was a Scooby Doo movie kind of like this called *Scooby Doo and the Cyber Chase* but I don't think that's the movie you're looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Code Lyoko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko) from 2003.

You can see them using the "tower targets" in the clip below and you can watch the entire series online [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn9zTBZVl6lu72s-6fXttZg/videos)

Comment: Yes that is it! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: The YouTube video is dead because of copyright claim

Comment: @AndrewT. - Better, although I'd prefer a cleaner copy

Comment: @Valorum the episodes are on Youtube, official channel and all, and the quality is pretty decent, take your pick: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn9zTBZVl6lu72s-6fXttZg/videos